# In WPF, how to know when an image has moved (due to another element Visibility changed to "Collapsed")?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `StackPanel` and an `Image`. When the user clicks a button, the `StackPanel` `Visibility` property is changing to `Collapsed`, making the image to change location.

Is there an event for that scenario? Another way to know when it is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that you are using a binding to change the `Visibility` of the `StackPanel` you could change the `setter` of the binding source to call a method on change:

```
Visibility vis;

public Visibility Vis
{
    get { return vis; }
    set
    {
        vis = value;
        imageLocationChanged();
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Vis");
    }
}

void imageLocationChanged()
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Note: If you have multiple bindings that may influence the images position, you would have to call this method from each setter

EDIT (reflecting OP's comment):

If setting the visibility in the code behind without binding then just call the method you need after setting the visibility:

```
stackpanel1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
imageLocationChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks. But I change the visibility by simply writing in the code behind `stackPanel1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`...

Comment: In that case, after doing that, call the function that you need to. `stackPanel1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; imageLocationChanged();`
Although this could get tedious if there are multiple things that could cause the image to move

Comment: It is tedious, but it works, so it answers my question. If you have a more elegant way, I would love to hear about it. :)